# Étymologie de «Javetz», nom d'origine de «Javel» (comme «Eau de Javel»)

Tags: étymologie, histoire

Est-ce-que quelqu’un connait l’étymologie / l'origine du mot **« Javetz »** - c'était le nom d'origine du « quartier de **Javel** » (à Paris), d'où vient le mot **« Eau de Javel »**

À mon avis, le mot **« Javetz »** parait comme un mot Allemand; aussi quand je l'ai googlé j’ai découvert qu'il s'agissait d'un nom de famille d'origine Juive - mais je ne sais pas si c'est nécessairement pertinent dans ce cas.

De tout façon, voici 2 extraits contenant le mot **« Javetz »** pour le contexte:

**Wikipédia.fr:**

*Le quartier était, au xve siècle, un lieu-dit baptisé **« Javetz »**. Au xviiie et jusqu'au xxe siècle, ces lieux utilisent parfois la graphie « Javelle ». L'uniformisation du xxe siècle a retenu la forme « Javel ».*

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartier_de_Javel

**Un autre (« Battle Paris»):**

« *Le hameau de Javel (à Paris) prit naissance au 15e siècle avec un petit port et un garage à bateaux, connu en 1485 sous le nom de **Javetz**.
En 1777, une fabrique de produits chimiques y vit le jour. De cette usine sortit l'hypochlorite de sodium, que l'on appela l'eau de Javel.
André Citroën y installe ses usines en 1933, ultramodernes pour l'époque avec une production vertigineuse de 1000 voitures par jour.
Sa démesure les fera fermer à la fin des années 1970, puis remplacer par le parc qui porte son nom.* »

https://battle.paris/districts/Javel/
Voila, Merci d’avoir lu :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Un [*javel*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/lexique-godefroy/javel) est un monceau, un îlot formé de sable et de limon.

L'histoire de Paris<sup>1</sup> nous apprend que :

> Au XV<sup>e</sup> siècle encore, [la Seine] non endigué[e] était plus large qu'aujourd'hui et ses rives marécageuses et submersibles. Au fil des crues et des décrues saisonnières se formaient des îles éphémères appelées *javeaux* ou *javetz*. Entre les joncs et les roseaux pullulaient les grenouilles  [...] la seule demeure des environs était la maison du passeur du bac de Javel. Au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle, un moulin à vent vint se poser (...) à la lisère de cette zone amphibie (...) En 1777, le comte d'Artois (...) y installa une manufacture de produits chimiques d'où sortaient de l'acide sulfurique, de l'acide nitrique (...) plus connu sous le nom d'eau de Javel.

Bien que de nos jours la langue ait retenu [javeau](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/javeau)  pour le singulier ce n'était pas le cas au XV<sup>e</sup> siècle où on distinguait le singulier *javel* du pluriel *javeaux*, comme l'indique le [Dictionnaire de Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/javel)<sup>2</sup>.

Le Quartier de Javel tient donc son nom du fait qu'au départ il était largement constitué d'îles (ou *javeaux*).  En ancien français la lettre z était une marque de pluriel. Et l'on peut penser que ***javetz*** est une forme plus ancienne de *javeaux*.

Quant à l'étymologie de *javel* pour désigner « un îlot formé de sable et de limon », il faut la trouver dans *javelle* :

> *gavele* (1190), aussi « tas, monceau » variante en ancien français *gevelle*, issu du latin populaire *gabella*, puis *javella* (846) d'origine gauloise<sup>3</sup>.

La même racine a donné le mot [*javelle*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/javelle) :  « Brassée de céréales ou d'oléagineux moissonnée à la faux ou à la moissonneuse, demeurant en petits tas sur le chaume, avant la mise en gerbe. »

---

Je complète avec ce que j'ai trouvé dans [*La prodigieuse histoire du nom des éléments*](https://books.google.fr/books/about/La_prodigieuse_histoire_du_nom_des_%C3%A9l%C3%A9.html?id=nhOGDwAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)<sup>4</sup> qui fait remonter la première mention écrite du nom du lieu au XIII<sup>e</sup> siècle sous la forme *insula de javeto* :

> Cet îlot est mentionné dans un manuscrit du XIII<sup>e</sup> siècle en latin médiéval sous le nom *insula de javeto*, qui est la première attestation connue du nom écrit *Javet* ou *Javelle*, et finalement *Javel* pour le lieu-dit, qui fut rattaché à Paris en 1860.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>  [*Promenades dans les villages de Paris-Grenelle*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=JlPTL0h-_XYC&dq=Javetz%20iles&hl=fr&source=gbs_navlinks_s) (Dominique Lesbros, Parigramme, 2008)

<sup>2</sup> *Dictionnaire de l’ancienne langue française et de tous ses dialectes du IX<sup>e</sup> au XV<sup>e</sup> siècle*.

<sup>3</sup>  *Dictionnaire culturel en langue Française*, sld Alain Rey.

<sup>4</sup> *La prodigieuse histoire du nom des éléments*, Pierre Avenas, Minh-Thu Dinh-Audouin, éditions edp sciences, 2019).</sup>

Comment: Quelle érudition ! Merci pour votre réponse approfondi et d'avoir pris le temps de rechercher cette question. Je n'ai trouvé quasiment rien à ce sujet donc je vous remercie  :-)

Comment: @user13764383  Et je te remercie aussi pour cette question très intéressante parce que j'avais quelques notions au départ mais pas tout et ça m'a obligée à creuser (avec plaisir), et je suis encore un peu frustrée parce que je ne suis pas arrivée à avoir accès à tous les documents que j'aurais souhaités. Si ça arrivait, je compléterais !

Comment: « Javelz » prononcé [jawelts] (je suis à peu près sûr de la finale -ts, moins des sons avant) était le pluriel régulier de « javel » au cas régime en ancien français avant l'évolution du L en U. Il ne me vient pas à l'esprit de mot en -el(z) où le son -elts s'est simplifié en enlevant le L et en gardant le T, mais c'est peut-être juste que je ne connais rien à l'ancien français, ou peut-être que ce nom propre s'est figé différemment des noms communs. Une fois la prononciation [jawets] (ou [jawetz]?) figée alors que le Z ne se prononçait plus [ts], il était naturel d'ajouter un T à l'écrit.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Il peut y avoir eu une « déformation  » de copiste, fréquent dans les manuscrits.